# want to display custome sort indicator in spark DataGrid?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder4.5

i have data-grid in my application and i want to customize my data-grid so i made a renderer for column and header, but now a problem is that **i want to make custom indicator which indicate a sorted column**.?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a custom header renderer by copying `spark.skins.spark.DefaultGridHeaderRenderer`
2. Find the inner component with id `defaultSortIndicator` and edit as you see fit
3. Assign the new renderer to a column: `<s:GridColumn headerRenderer="path.to.MyHeaderRenderer" />`
4. If you want to assign it to all columns by default, you can also create a custom DataGrid skin and replace the `headerRenderer` inner component with your custom renderer:

.

```
<fx:Component id="headerRenderer">
    <myskins:MyHeaderRenderer />
</fx:Component>
```