# Flex DataGrid Spark HeaderRenderer Sort Icon

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex-spark

I am trying to have an icon for one of my columns in my DataGrid. I initialized the DataGrid and put the columns like so:

```
<s:GridColumn dataField="Test"
              itemRenderer="ColorGradientItemRenderer"
              sortCompareFunction="numeric_sort('Test')">
    <s:headerRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer chromeColor="0xFFFFFF">
                <s:Image source="@Embed('img/test.jpg')" width="75" height="75" />
            </s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:headerRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```

I see the image fine on the header, the problem is that when I click on the image to sort, the little arrow indicating the sort direction doesn't show up. How can I get it to show up? It would be great if I could just insert some mxml inline here and not have to create multiple mxml renderer files to do this.

Comment: Since you are creating a custom headerRenderer I think it will be up to you to implement the little arrow.  Since you are extending the DefaultGridHeaderRenderer, I suspect that your image is covering up the arrow.  I'm guessing, but I bet if you use creationComplete on the renderer and use setChildIndex to set the Image to be Index 0; the arrows will show up.  Not elegant, but probably functional.

Comment: I tried changing the depths actually, didn't work. Also tried moving the image way to the left and alphaing it down - arrow didn't show up. It's strange it's like it overrode the arrows. I ended up making new files for the renderer... A bit annoying but what can you do

Answer (score 0):

You need to skin the defaultSortIndicator in a custom header skin. See this question : [want to display custome sort indicator in spark DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294999/want-to-display-custome-sort-indicator-in-spark-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the datagrid's sortByColumns method, or extend the datagrid and add this method to it:

```
public function PlaceSortIndicator(columnIndex:uint, descending:Boolean):void
{
    if(columnIndex >= 0 && columns != null && columns.length > columnIndex)
    {
        var column:GridColumn = columns.getItemAt(columnIndex) as GridColumn;
        if(column != null)
        {
            column.sortDescending = descending;
            if (columnHeaderGroup)
                columnHeaderGroup.visibleSortIndicatorIndices = new <int>[columnIndex];
        }
    }
}
```